# How to generate deterministic keypairs using ed25519

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumj

I am trying to implement my wallet using ed25519 curve, i was using tweetnacl from this link  "https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js" its working, But i want to generate deterministic key-pair creation  from the 12 word seed.similar to eth-lightwallet/metamask. How i can create it,using edd25519 curve need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use function: **nacl.sign.keyPair.fromSeed(seed)**

For generating random seed,
use npm package **[bip39](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bip39)**

https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip39

Usage:

// Generate a random mnemonic (12 words) (uses crypto.randomBytes under the hood)

**var mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic()**

// Convert 12 word mnemonic to  32 byte seed

**bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic)**